# Async child_process.exec with TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, error-handling

I'm trying to use a `child_process.exec` call with TypeScript, and error handling seems excessively hard to get right.

Here's the gist of what I'm trying to do:

```
import { promisify } from "util";
import { exec, ExecException } from "child_process";

const execPromise = promisify(exec);

export const myCommand = async (param: string) => {
  const { stdout, stderr } = await execPromise(`my_command ${param}`);
  return {
    stdout,
    stderr,
    // some other fields
  };
};
```

This works fine as long as `my_command` returns `0`.

Now, `my_command` can sometimes return `1`, but it should be an error, not an exception. It's kinda normal and I want to handle it. With promisify though, it becomes an Exception, so I tried to handle it this way:

```
let stdout, stderr: string;
try {
  const { stdout: execStdout, stderr: execStderr } = await execPromise(`my_command ${param}`);
  stdout = execStdout;
  stderr = execStderr;
} catch (e: unknown) {
  // ???
}
```

Here's what I tried for exception handling:

```
if (e instanceof ExecException) {}
```

but it fails with `'ExecException' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`

I also tried:

```
if ("stdout" in e) {}
```

because I want to retrieve `stdout` from the error but it fails with `Object is of type 'unknown'.`.

I then tried to force a type assertion with:

```
e as ExecException
```

It kinda works but:

- it's risky
- I noticed [ExecException](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/interfaces/_node_modules__types_node_child_process_d_._child_process_.execexception.html) doesn't have the `stdout`/`stderr` fields that it should have, so I still can't get them in case of error, which makes no sense...

So I'm a bit stuck on what I should do. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a Type Guard:

```
function isStdError(err: any): err is { stderr: string } {
    return !!err.stderr
}
```

Then in your code:

```
try {
    await exec(`my_command`)
} catch (e) {
    if (isStdError(e)) {
        console.log(e.stderr)
    } else {
        throw e
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually stderr could be empty, but that could still be a stderr, so maybe typeguard should be: `return typeof err.stderr === "string"`